# Can I write a custom template for the Liferay blog portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to make major changes to the layout of the Liferay blog portlet. Is it possible to define my own template somehow? I want to be able to change the markup. Kind of the same way you can make templates for Web content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the blogs portlet doesn't have the same capability as WebContent. However, depending on your setup, you might be able to "mimic" a blog with WebContent: Categorize your content according to your requirements, publish on AssetPublisher and stick a label "Blog" on to it.

It depends a bit on the number of blog authors and the location of the blogs you have: After all, you'll have to enable them to author/edit webcontent in one site. If that's not a problem, use this. As you might use a defined template, you might also be able to automate a bit of extra work when you provide a custom portlet for article input - but that would be the advanced usecase.

Comment: That was my back up idea as well. I'm probably gonna go with that then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Hook would be the best option in your case. With Hook you can easily override any jsp in Liferay portal. You can find example [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/overriding-a-jsp)

Comment: Thanks, I will have to look into that. Do you have any input on that idea @Olaf Kock?